# Extract macOS Unified Logging by an app?

Tags: macos, logging

Is there a way to extract log messages generated by the new macOS [unified logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) API by a sandboxed application? Just the log messages originated from the app itself, *not* the entire system nor other applications.

It looks like the `log collect` command needs to be run by root, hence not suitable to be invoked by an app trying to extract its own log statements.

The use case is primarily for the purpose of packaging those logs into a support e-mail to send it back from the user's machine for analysis by the developer.